# Component size in JPanel

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, layout-manager

I've created a frame with inside two `JPanel` objects. This panel doesn't occupy all the space in a frame but only a part. I need they occupy equally the available space inside frame.

```
container = frame.getContentPane();
matricepc = new JPanel();
matrice = new JPanel();
matrice.setLayout(new GridLayout(griglia.getRow(), griglia.getColumn()));
matricepc.setLayout(new GridLayout(griglia.getRow(), griglia.getColumn()));
container.add(matricepc,BorderLayout.NORTH);
container.add(matrice,BorderLayout.SOUTH);
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
container.setLayout(new GridLayout(0,1));
container.add(matricepc);
container.add(matrice);
```

EDIT: This ´GridLayout´ constructor expects two parameters: The first one is the number of rows, and the second one is the number of columns. When *either* of them is `0`, then the respective number will be chosen based on the other one, and the number of components that are added. In this example: You specify that you want `1` column (and the number of rows does not matter - but since you add 2 components, the number of rows will be `2` - thus, you could also have written `new GridLayout(2, 1)`.

EDIT2: Not really related to the original question, but more or less a general hint: Don't underestimate the power of **nesting** in order to achieve a particular layout. In this case, you can give

- A BorderLayout to the main container (the content pane)
- A GridLayout to a new panel that only contains the matrix-panels

and put the 'panelForMatrices' into the main container:

```
container.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

JPanel panelForMatrices = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0,1));
panelForMatrices.add(matricepc);
panelForMatrices.add(matrice);
container.add(panelForMatrices, BorderLayout.CENTER);

JPanel lateralPanel = ...
container.add(lateralPanel, BorderLayout.EAST);
```

Comment: Can you explane me what means (0,1) ?

Comment: Added an EDIT with an explaination

Comment: Added another EDIT with an example